# Mean Month values out put should acending by year and month

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to take out put ascending by year and month...... i try it but it not work well.my query is.

```
CREATE  VIEW `avg_month_all` AS 
   SELECT `a`.`year` AS `year`,
          `a`.`month` AS `month`,
          `a`.`temp_air` AS `temp_air`,
          `a`.`rel_humid` AS `rel_humid`,
          `a`.`soil_temp_5` AS `soil_temp_5`,
          `a`.`soil_temp_20` AS `soil_temp_20`,
          `a`.`soil_temp_30` AS `soil_temp_30`,
          `a`.`soil_temp_60` AS `soil_temp_60`,
          `a`.`air_pressure` AS `air_pressure`,
          `a`.`dry_temp` AS `dry_temp`,
          `a`.`wet_temp` AS `wet_temp`,
          `b`.`run` AS `run`,
          `b`.`velocity` AS `velocity`,
          `c`.`rainfall` AS `rainfall`,
          `c`.`evep` AS `evep`,
          `c`.`max_temp` AS `max_temp`,
          `c`.`min_temp` AS `min_temp`,
          `c`.`sunshine_hrs` AS `sunshine_hrs`
   FROM ((`avg_month_val` `a` 
   LEFT JOIN `avg_month_velo` `b`
   ON(((`a`.`year` = `b`.`year`) AND (`a`.`month` = `b`.`month`))))
   LEFT JOIN `avg_month_val1` `c`
   ON(((`a`.`year` = `c`.`year`) AND (`a`.`month` = `c`.`month`))))
   ORDER BY (`a`.`year` ASC AND `a`.`month` ASC);
```

Comment: my out put is like this (2008,2,values...),(2008,5,values...)......but i want to take out put (2008,1,values...),(2008,2,values...)...... like that . i add this (a.year ASC anda.month ASC). it is no work well

Comment: Please clean up your question. Your use of backticks has confused StackOverflow.com where they declare inline a span of text to be presented as source code. Also, it's best if you try to simplify your code example – we don't care about "soil_temp_20" versus "soil_temp_60" for example.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY \`a\`.\`year\` ASC, \`a\`.\`month\` ASC` instead of `ORDER BY (\`a\`.\`year\` ASC AND \`a\`.\`month\` ASC)` -> using a comma `,` instead of `AND`

Comment: I found the Answer- order by `a`.`year`,`a`.`month` ASC @Sean it is OK